# Box2D ChainShape VertexCount=0

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, physics

Im working with Box2D on LibGDX, and I'm working with bodies and collisions etc..

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291644/box2d-collisions-error), i had the problem of a body colliding with another, when it shouldn't do that. 

Now after Knowing that i need to use ChainShapes, i started with that. 

Whenever u run my project, i get an assertion error:

> Assertion failed: (count >= 2), function CreateChain, file
>   /Users/tom/Coding/slave/workspace/libgdx-mac/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.cpp,
>   line 62.

So i tried a small debug to print the vertex count, and the vertex out printed as 0.

Problem is that i am adding the vertices and they dont appear to be added...

Code for adding verticies:

```
    chain = new ChainShape();
    chain.setNextVertex(new Vector2((posx - size) / PPM, (posy + size) / PPM));
    chain.setNextVertex(new Vector2((posx + size) / PPM, (posy + size) / PPM));
    chain.setNextVertex(new Vector2((posx + size) / PPM, (posy - size) / PPM));
    chain.setNextVertex(new Vector2((posx - size) / PPM, (posy - size) / PPM));
    System.out.println(chain.getVertexCount());
```

Vertex count is printed as 0, thats why i am getting the error, I dont know how to fix it, so please help :)

Comment: Would this help? (not tested)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381381/chainshape-in-box2d/35668026

Comment: @javaLover I tried that, and i am still achieving the same error, i actually searched a lot, but found nothing useful, thats why i posted here

Comment: @Liwaa what is the value and type of these variable `posx`,`posy` , `size` , `PPM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `ChainShape` in this way :

```
ChainShape chain=new ChainShape();

Vector2 vector[]=new Vector2[4];
vector[0]=new Vector2((posx - size) / PPM, (posy + size) / PPM);
vector[1]=new Vector2((posx + size) / PPM, (posy + size) / PPM);
vector[2]=new Vector2((posx + size) / PPM, (posy - size) / PPM);
vector[3]=new Vector2((posx - size) / PPM, (posy - size) / PPM);

chain.createChain(vector);

System.out.println(chain.getVertexCount());  // 4 on console
```

If still you've problem, check the value of `posx`, `posy`, `size` , `PPM`